# Strongloop REST API: change password

Tags: rest, authentication, strongloop

I would like to implement a simple "change password" so that an authorised user can do so. 
Experimenting with the explorer, I managed to write an ACL for the user model (my extension of the default User) that allow a user to change its data:

```
{
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "accessType": "WRITE",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
}
```

However, when I try from explorer the endpoint PUT /users/{id} with new credentials, it fails silently, i.e., it returns ok, but perform no password change:

REQUEST:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/users/6?access_token=6CVOuMZCLB8deH7e5t8xJtzDlWjU98WUCRCSGO6zdjW0bhSR6Z20vddl7dIWepF8
```

DATA:

```
{

  "credentials":
    {"email":"pepito@example.com", "password": "ppito"}

}
```

(User 6 is already authenticated).

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "realm": null,
  "username": "pepito",
  "credentials": {
    "email": "pepito@example.com",
    "password": "ppito"
  },
  "challenges": null,
  "email": "pepito@example.com",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "verificationToken": "2a9c25fa6e858db5894f98cd3f0be3694041f148781896cb5775ff30da1f367c7843ac4b60013fd47c34c6f1a862a5cabb77cf2807c101da7f2acfcdd8853ec7",
  "status": null,
  "created": null,
  "lastUpdated": null,
  "id": 6
}
```

However, the password remain unchanged (tried with logout/login from the explorer).

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with password is different game. In order to change the password use the following code:

```
var AccessToken = Customer.app.models.AccessToken;
        AccessToken.findById(access_token, function (err, token) {
            if (err) cb(err);
            else {
                Customer.findById(token.userId, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        cb(err);
                    }

                    if (user == null || user == undefined) cb(new Error('user is undefined'));

                    user.updateAttribute('password', password, function (err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            cb(err);
                        }

                        cb(null, 'success');
                    });
                });
            }
        })
```

**updateAttribute** is what allows you to make the updates.

I've never been able to change password from swagger.